# Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Beta 2 Debugger Problem

Tags: android, android-studio

When I want to analyze Breakpoint, the problem on the screen occurs. Debugger hangs. Is there a specific solution for this situation?

[image: Android Studio breakpoint debugger problem]

Comment: Did you find a solution? Had this problem for a few hours and thought was something with my code. 
Switch to Flamingo and started working.